# Python Pandas - Select multiple rows if the ID is the same and one of the rows is equal to a number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the issue of getting all the rows if an ID has a score equal to 1.0 and has more than one row in the database.

Dataframe:

```
INDEX  ORG_ID  Score
1      5467    1.0
2      5467    .897
3      5467    .50
4      8979    1.0
```

Expected Outcome:

```
INDEX  ORG_ID  Score
1      5467    1.0
2      5467    .897
3      5467    .50
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output, you can use the following syntax

```
>>> df[df.ORG_ID.isin(df.ORG_ID.value_counts()[df.ORG_ID.value_counts() > 1].keys())]

ORG_ID  Score
0   5467    1.000
1   5467    0.897
2   5467    0.500
```

But the example you gave doesn't have any instances of multiple `ORG_ID` values where the instance does *not* contain a `Score` = 1. Consider the following dataframe:

```
ORG_ID  Score
0   5467    1.000
1   5467    0.897
2   5467    0.500
3   8979    1.000
4   1111    0.897
5   1111    0.500
```

To achieve the desired result, use the following lines of code

```
>>> # Get all rows with an ID that appears multiple times
>>> is_duplicate = df.ORG_ID.isin(df.ORG_ID.value_counts()[df.ORG_ID.value_counts() > 1].keys())

>>> # Get all rows if the ID has at least one score = 1
>>> score_equal_to_1 = df.ORG_ID.isin(df[df.Score == 1].ORG_ID.values)

>>> # Apply both constraints to the dataframe
>>> df[is_duplicate & score_euqal_to_1]

    ORG_ID  Score
0   5467    1.000
1   5467    0.897
2   5467    0.500
```

Comment: This is helpful thank you! It achieved my desired result.

If I wanted to get all the rows where the ORG_ID does not have a score = to 1.0 at all how to I adjust "score_greater_than_1"

Comment: ```score_not_equal_to_1 = df.ORG_ID.isin(df[df.Score != 1].ORG_ID.values)```